# Can I pass an array parameter into a CTE?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

In PostgreSQL, I want to do something like

```
WITH vars AS %s
SELECT * FROM table2
   INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.t1id = table1.id
   WHERE table1.var in (select * from vars)
   AND table2.var in (select * from vars)
```

And then pass in the `%s` as an ARRAY parameter. Is there any reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `VALUES`, like in:

```
WITH vars
     (var)
AS
(
VALUES (1),
       (2),
       (3)
)
...
WHERE ... nmuloc IN (SELECT var
                            FROM vars) ...
```

Or `unnest()`:

```
WITH vars
     (var)
AS
(
SELECT unnest('{1,2,3}'::integer[])
)
...
WHERE ... nmuloc IN (SELECT var
                            FROM vars) ...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=583e15ee164afae1ad7d3024a369e3bd)

But you can also directly use the array with `= ANY`:

```
WHERE ... nmuloc = ANY('{1,2,3}'::integer[]) ...
```